# How fo fix webfont in Firefox and IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, font-face

I have a problem with special Webfont Characters in German language with (Ö,Ä,Ü). In Firefox and IE it looks like this now:

[image]

In Chrome and Safari is fine. What can I do to fix this problem, any idea?

The Fonts are:

- Neue Helvetica eText W04 45 Light
- Neue Helvetica W04 43 Light Extended

Comment: Post the code of your embedded font for starters. If you have an example of the code is even better.

Comment: I guess you can make a live jsfiddle-like code snippet right here, in the question: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/